# How to simplify jQuery code , plugin, scroll to the block

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to simplify jQuery code. 
If I have 1 page with several different blocks. 
I need to duplicate this code multiple times to use different elements?
How to write 1 code for multiple blocks ?

```
  $('.go_to').click( function(){ 
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); 
            if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {  
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); 
            }
            return false; 
        });

    <a class="go_to" href="#elm">button</a> или <a class="go_to" href=".elm">block-scroll</a>

$('.go_to-1').click( function(){ 
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); 
            if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {  
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); 
            }
            return false; 
        });

    <a class="go_to-1" href="#elm">button</a> или <a class="go_to-1" href=".elm">block-scroll</a>

$('.go_to-2').click( function(){ 
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); 
            if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {  
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); 
            }
            return false; 
        });

    <a class="go_to-2" href="#elm">button</a> или <a class="go_to-2" href=".elm">block-scroll</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example, the simplest way is to select multiple elements with jquery using a comma separated list, and define the click handler all of them at once:

```
  $('.go_to, .go_to-1, .go_to-2').click( function(){ 
        //on click code
  });
```

I am assuming you need different classes for the anchors, but if not, you could just give them all the same class (for example `class="go_to"`) and use

```
  $('.go_to').click( function(){ 
        //on click code
  });
```